# MySQL can't connect to database remotely (111 Connection refused)

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have a MySQL database running on my PC (win10) and am trying to access it from a Raspberry Pi using python. The database is started and I can establish a connection on the PC, however the RPI is having trouble connecting. I have the following python code:

```
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
   host="127.0.0.1",
   user="root",
   passwd="*******",
   database="facial_recog_database")
```

The error code I'm getting is the following:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

I've tried searching the internet and the only things I've found are changing the `bind-address` in the file `my.ini`. However, in my case, this file does not have `bind-address` in it?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is a special address that means "this computer".  So the raspberry pi is trying to connect to itself, and you don't have a MySQL server running on the pi.  Try using the address of the Windows 10 PC.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you very much! This fixed my issue